# What if I ignore New CPU installed...message

Tags: motherboard, bios

The specification of my desktop computer is as

**Processor**: AMD FX-8320, **Motherboard**: ASUS M5A97 (AMD 970 Chipset), **RAM**: 16GB Kingston HyperX Fury, **HD**: 1TB WD Black and **SMPS**: CoolerMaster 650W

Due to some issue, the processor was replaced by the AMD. After installing the new processor (FX-8320), I see an error message during POST:

**New CPU installed! Please enter setup to configure your system. Press F1 to Run SETUP**

After pressing **F1**, I press **F8** for Boot Menu, then I select **P3:WDC..** (Hard Drive)

Then Windows login screen appears. I saved booting priority by **F10**. However, after every restart, I need to follow these steps after pressing **F1**.

I replaced onboard 3V battery and discussed with ASUS also. I have gone through all possible troubleshooting steps with the guidance of ASUS.
The BIOS of motherboard is already updated. However, I re-flashed the BIOS and I selected default loading.

At the end issue is not resolved and ASUS says, this issue is because of motherboard so disable **Wait for 'F1' If Error** and continue to use.

I know disabling **Wait for 'F1' If Error** is not the solution of this problem. It is just ignoring the error message.

Please let me know, if I ignore the error message, is there any possibility of further hardware issue? And if I continue by ignoring this error message, what precautions do I need to take to avoid further hardware issue?

With Regards

John

Comment: Try loading default settings in the bios and save changes.

Comment: Did you contact Asus support since they changed the processor?

Comment: I did all possible troubleshooting steps with the guidance of Asus. Also I selected default loading but issue not resolved. At the end Asus suggested, disable Wait for 'F1' If Error and continue to use and this issue is because of motherboard.

Comment: Pls guide me; if I ignore the error message, is there any possibility of further hardware issues in motherboard, processor, RAM or hard drive? And if I continue by ignoring this error message, is there precaution so that the possibility of further hardware issue in the motherboard and processor would be less?